# Improving the running time of SQL query

Tags: sql

Assume the query below take a long time to run. To improve the running time of this SQL query, which of the options below are the best way to do so?

```
SELECT Name
FROM People
WHERE Birth_Date > CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATE) ;
```

People is the name of the table.
Now there are 4 options:

1. Replace the expression `Birth_Date` with `CAST (Birth_Date AS DATE)` to avoid type conversions.
2. `CREATE INDEX IDX ON People (Birth_Date, Name)`
3. `CREATE INDEX IDX ON People (Name, Birth_Date)`
4. Create a view that consists of this query with the actual date of birth as an input parameter.

Which of the option is the best and why?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using. Performance tuning is highly database specific

Comment: Avoid using casting in the where clause, rather you could use a stored generated column, index it and then use it in where clause.

Comment: I doubt if there is a type conversion involved. Use option 2. Btw, how many rows are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2.

Option 1 performs an unnecessary type conversion as we may assume that `Birth_Date` is already a `DATE` (or compatible type), why else would `'2000-01-01'` be cast to `DATE`? It would not help to speed up the query, only to slow it down more, because of the extra casting.

Option 2 creates an index whose first member is `Birth_Date`, so the engine can use an efficient search in the index to find the record with the least `Birth_Date` that meets the `WHERE` condition and then output all records from there on, following the index order.

Option 3 creates an index that is not useful, since `Birth_Date` is not its first member, so it cannot be used to efficiently find the record with the least `Birth_Date`, nor to traverse records in order of `Birth_Date`.

Option 4 is not possible, as views don't take parameters. Even if a certain database engine would know about this concept, it would only affect the right side of the `WHERE` condition, not the algorithm that the database engine can use for retrieving the matching records.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,  you only need create index on People(Birth_Date).
Because, only this column is involved the selectivity as the condition.

1. Please don't CAST (Birth_Date AS ),  casting on the column type will cause the related index no effect unless you create function index. No need to do it.
2. For your 2 and 3,  there is no need to create combound index. Column name is not in the condition list. No help for the efficiency.
3. this is a simple query, no need to create a view for that.